# Deleting Strings from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to code the Mastermind game, but instead of the user cracking the computer's code, the computer must crack the user's code. I am having trouble in the response method, where I attempt to remove possible codes that cannot be correct. The example I was testing was that the secret code is 223, with the tokens being 1,2, and 3, and the position being 3. The computer first guesses 1 1 1, which I say is incorrect. Then, the computer should remove all strings containing "1" from the ArrayList, but it doesn't remove anything at all. What have I done wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MMplayer {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    String[] tokencolors; //the tokens the user enters
    ArrayList <String> possibleGuesses = new ArrayList <String>();
    String [] remainingGuess; //the number of remaining possible guesses
    String lastGuess; //the last guess that was made
    int guessNum = 0; //guess count
    int positions = 0;
    int ccpw; //"color correct, position wrong"
    int ccpc; //"color correct, position correct"

public static void main (String[] args){

    //This sets up the introduction so the player knows how to play
    System.out.println("Hello, and welcome to Mastermind!");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("You will choose a certain number of tokens to play with (these can be anything, like colors, names, or fruit).\n"
            + "Then you will choose the number of those tokens that you'd like to use in the game (called the position)."
            + "\nThe computer will then try to guess the correct name and location of your tokens. ");
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number of tokens and their names (up to six tokens), and the number of positions (up to four)."
            + "\nJust remember that to make it harder for the computer, pick more tokens than you actually want to use. ");

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Enter number of tokens now: ");
    //number of tokens, makes sure it is at most 6 
    int aryLength = scan.nextInt();
    if (aryLength > 6){
        System.out.println("Please enter at most six tokens.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter token names now, pressing enter after each: ");
    String [] tokencolors = new String[aryLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < aryLength; i++){
        tokencolors[i] = scan.next();
    }

    System.out.println("Enter number of positions now: ");
    int position = scan.nextInt();
    if (position > 4){
        System.out.println("Please enter at most 4 positions.");
        System.exit(0);
    }


    MMplayer player = new MMplayer(tokencolors, position);
}

public MMplayer(String[] cTokencolors, int cPositions) {
    tokencolors = cTokencolors;
    positions = cPositions;

    holder();

}
public void holder (){

    if (guessNum == 0){ //if this is the very first guess
        if (positions == 1){ //if there is one position
            for (int i = 0; i < tokencolors.length; i++){
                possibleGuesses.add(tokencolors[i]);
            }
        }
        else if (positions == 2){ //if there are two positions
            for (int i = 0; i < tokencolors.length; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < tokencolors.length; j++){
                    possibleGuesses.add(tokencolors[i] + " " + tokencolors[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        else if (positions == 3){ //if there are three positions
            for (int i = 0; i < tokencolors.length; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < tokencolors.length; j++){
                    for (int k = 0; k < tokencolors.length; k++){
                        possibleGuesses.add(tokencolors[i] + " " + tokencolors[j] + " " + tokencolors[k]);

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else if (positions == 4){ //if there are four positions
            for (int i = 0; i < tokencolors.length; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < tokencolors.length; j++){
                    for (int k = 0; k < tokencolors.length; k++){
                        for (int l = 0; l < tokencolors.length; l++){
                            possibleGuesses.add(tokencolors[i] + " " + tokencolors[j] + " " + tokencolors[k] + " " + tokencolors[l]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Number of positions is invalid.");
            newGame();
        }

        System.out.println("Guess: " + possibleGuesses.get(0));
        lastGuess = possibleGuesses.get(0);
        guessNum++;

        System.out.println("First enter how many tokens were right, but had the wrong position: ");
        ccpw = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Next, enter how many tokens were right and had the right position: ");
        ccpc = scan.nextInt();

        response(ccpw, ccpc);
    }


}

//  public String[] nextMove() {// return the next guess
//
//  } 


public void response(int colorsRightPositionWrong, int positionsAndColorRight) {
    ccpw = colorsRightPositionWrong;
    ccpc = positionsAndColorRight;




    if (ccpc == positions){
        System.out.println("The computer has won!");
    }
    else {
        if (guessNum == 1){
            String guess = tokencolors[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < possibleGuesses.size(); i++){
                if (possibleGuesses.get(i).equals(guess)){
                    possibleGuesses.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Remaining guesses: " + possibleGuesses);
    }



}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Based on my understanding of your description it appears that you have issue on the line shown below where you should check for contains instead instead of equals:
if (guessNum == 1){
            String guess = tokencolors[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < possibleGuesses.size(); i++){
                //check for contains below?
                if (possibleGuesses.get(i).equals(guess)){
                    possibleGuesses.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
..
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I just tried contains, and it deleted about half the strings it was supposed to. If I use tokens 1 and 2 and use positions 2, attempting to delete the strings that contain 1 leaves me with [1 2, 2 2].

Answer (score 0):

You're using `tokencolors[0]` as your first guess, which would be "1", in this case.
That causes nothing to be removed if you use `equals` (because all the possibilities have the format "1 1 1"), as you're describing.

If using `contains`, what happens is that you're modifying the list while iterating, which is a bad idea.
Analysing each value of `i`:

## i = 0

guesses.get(0) == "1 1"

"1 1" contains "1", so removes. Guesses are now [1 2, 2 1, 2 2]

## i = 1

guesses.get(1) == "2 1"

"2 1" contains "1", so removes. Guesses are now [1 2, 2 2]

## i = 2

At this point the `i >= guesses.size()`, so the loops ends.

## Using iterators

You should use an iterator for removing things in a list:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = guesses.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    String item = it.next();
    if (item.contains(guess)) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```